# How to customize the look & feel of primefaces components?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How do I style a primefaces components & specify their positions on web pages ? Links to any sample downloadable application would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Position of components**:

Primefaces has some components that have position attribute(s) such as [`p:dialog`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogHome.jsf):

```
<p:dialog header=”Header Text” widgetVar=”dialog” position=”10,50”>
 ...
</p:dialog>
```

In the example the position is given as [x,y] pair related to the top left corner of the browser window. Values such as "top", "bottom", "left", "right" or "center" are also allowed here. If the attribute is omitted, the position of a dialog is centered.

For all other components css positioning can be use either defined by the `style` or `styleClass` attribute which is available for a lot of Primefaces components or defined in a separate css layout.

The following example sets an absolute position for the `p:dataTable`:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{testBean.selectOptions}" var="item"
             style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:240px;">
```

Primefaces even comes with an own [`p:layout`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutHome.jsf) tag that can be used for positioning as well.

**Style**

This can be accomplished using [Primefaces themes](http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html). Furthermore, the [Primefaces documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html) (you have to pay for since version 2.1) lists all css style classes for each component. You can adapt them to fit your needs.