# How to build custom themes for Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How do I build custom themes for primefaces ? Can I do it using themeroller ?

Comment: This question is overly broad  and rhetorical. What exactly is the problem you're facing? In your on a related subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260679/how-to-customize-the-look-feel-of-primefaces-components, you got a link to http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html which in turn mentions and links to http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/. Isn't that already an answer at its own? (the answer is "Yes")

Answer (score 6):

See the primfaces website ( http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html ) to make your theme in themeroller then download it.

See this video, also: http://vimeo.com/14235640

Comment: +1 for the link to the video - this is a far easier approach then the difficult, hand-rolled JAR approach that is advocated in the PrimeFaces PDF documentation (which is made even harder if you are a Maven user and need to supply your JAR from a lib folder and then refer to it in your web.xml file!)

Answer (score 4):

Found this online tool for converting themeroller zip to primefaces jar, with instructions for maven usage: https://themeroller.osnode.com/

Answer (score 2):

you can use PrimeFaces Theme Converter http://www.pftc.de

it works with jquery-ui-1.10.3

Answer (score 2):

see this website http://jqueryui.com/
If you want to make custom theme select theme in task bar and go to theme roller 
1.select Roll Your Own button and then make a changes as your need.
2.If you want to use existing theme and you want to change the color means select gallery button 
  i)select a favorite themeii)Edit a theme changes the coloriii)Download theme 
 Finally you get a zip file.Extract a zip file it contains image folder and css file.
Copy image and css file.Put images in web content/common/images folder and css file into web content/resources/css.
Finally use this link to display your custom theme use the css file

```
    <link href="./resources/css/example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (at least as of 2.2.1) to extract out the images and stylesheets of the individual theme and refer to them dynamically through code.  I believe there is a Primefaces component in version 3 that does this for you however.

The following is an example of how I acheive this.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/themes/#{sessionScopedBean.theme}/skin.css" />
```

You can use that existing theme as a template and make changes as you see fit.  You can also change the `theme` property of the session bean to dynamically change your themes.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is covered by chapter 8.2 of [Primefaces documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html). Yes, you can use themeroller, optionally you can create a JAR file of your theme. Then you can use it like the other predefined Primefaces themes.